# 'value trying to be set on copy' warning

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I'm trying to do a simple replacement of values in multiple columns of a **subset** of a data frame with the .loc function, using the following process:

**Original dataframe**

```py
    cols = [f'Q{i:03}' for i in range(1, 50)]
    vals = np.random.choice(['a', 'b'], (10, len(cols)))
    df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=cols)
```

From the original dataframe I take a subset of columns using:

```py
df2=df.iloc[:,np.r_[0:15,21,22,24:40]]
```

And finally I replace the values in the subset of columns using

```py
    df2.loc[:,'Q014':'Q032'] = 
    df2.loc[:,'Q014':'Q032'].replace({'a':1,'b':0})
```

I don't understand why I get this warning

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
> using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

I've read the documentation but I cannot see what the problem is. Someone please help me to understand. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The following article explains clearly. Please refer https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/11/3-ways-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas/

If your code is working as intended, you could turn off the warning by `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None`.

Edit: I am unable to leave comments hence posting in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to answer your question with this single line because your code can't trigger `SettingWithCopyWarning` as it. It happens probably earlier in your code.

```
cols = [f'Q{i:03}' for i in range(1, 50)]
vals = np.random.choice(['a', 'b'], (10, len(cols)))
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=cols)

df.loc[:,'Q014':'Q032'] = df.loc[:,'Q014':'Q032'].replace({'a':1,'b':0})
```

Output:

```
>>> df.loc[:, 'Q014':'Q032']
  Q014 Q015 Q016 Q017 Q018 Q019 Q020 Q021 Q022 Q023 Q024 Q025 Q026 Q027 Q028 Q029 Q030 Q031 Q032
0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0
1    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    1
2    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
3    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    1    1    0
4    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
5    0    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
6    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    1
7    1    1    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1
8    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    0
9    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0
```

Comment: Thank you @Corralien. I edited my question based on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Basically. when you are using DOT NOTATION (like df.your_column)

1. part of the code tries to GET something
2. The other part is trying to SET something

To avoid this, you can use the syntax with LOC.

There is a youtube video  [How do I avoid a SettingWithCopyWarning in pandas?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4R4WsDJ-KVc)

Maybe you can understand better what happens under the hood.

Also, I think that @Norwegian Salmon has the correct answer

> Note: I checked if this post is a question that someone can suggest an youtube video. [Check this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104179/can-i-add-a-youtube-video-to-my-answer-in-stack-overflow) from  @Michael Perrotta . In this case, I think so... If someone disagrees, please let me know.  I just want to help and respect all the community.